# Logout user automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have standart laravels authentication system created with `php artisan make:auth`.

In some conditions, I need automatically logout user from system. I tried somethong like:

```
if(condition) {
    return redirect('/logout');
}
```

This trows `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`

1) why trows this error? because when user clicks same link (laravel's default logout link), then logout works.

and second question: What is correct way, to logout user automatically ?

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` has something to do with HTTP verbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`logout` is a `POST` method route and redirecting is a `GET` method

The correct way is to call the `logout` function on the `Auth` facade, this will remove the user object from the session, you can redirect to any guest available route after that

```php
if(condition) {
    auth()->logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: good answer ... minor note, that isn't the Auth facade (just being technical)

Comment: Thanks @lagbox, I avoided writing the Facade to avoid the import or the \